# How to send Chromium debugger a command (set breakpoint)?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm using an advanced text editor (but not a totally IDE) while developing web based applications, so I do rely on Chromium's debugger.

I want to provide an easier way to put a temporary breakpoints in the runtime via text editor's window.

All I need is to be able to send a breakpoint information in the runtime to the Chromium Debugger. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need to connect your text editor to the Chrome Developer Tools or write some small(ish) programs that connect to the Chrome Developer Tools and issue the appropriate `setBreakpoint` command.

Setting the breakpoint is basically just sending some JSON to the Chrome Developer Tools, but for that to work, you need to first ask Chrome for a Websocket connection, connect to that Websocket and then issue your command. There are various ways of automating the Chrome Developer Tools for Pyhon, NodeJS, C# and Perl ([written by me](https://metacpan.org/release/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.24)), so if you can tell us what language you are comfortable in, we can likely suggest concrete libraries to do the communication with Chrome / Chromium for you.

#### See also

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger#method-setBreakpoint

Comment: I would prefer NodeJS and my ide (Atom) would support that one out of the box.

Comment: This is a NodeJS based lib for CDP that I stumbled across today: https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface